# Given two planes find the value of k such that the angle between two planes is ${\frac\pi3}$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, vectors

How can we determine the coefficients of the components of a plane when given the angle?

I am given two planes $$\Pi_1: 2x-y+2z=5$$
$$\Pi_2: x+2y+kz=3$$

and asked to find the value of k such that the angle between the planes is 
${\frac\pi3}$.

I know how to find the angle when given planes (with all of the coefficients) but I can't find any examples of how to find k when given the angle.

I think I'm supposed to use the equation $cos\theta=\frac{\vec{n_1}\cdot\vec{n_2}}{||{\vec{n_1}||||\vec{n_2}}||}$

$$\theta={\frac\pi3}$$

The normal vectors are $\vec{n_1}=<2,-1,2>$,  $\vec{n_2}=<1,2,k>$

The dot product between the two normal vectors is ${\vec{n_1}\cdot\vec{n_2}}=2k$

The magnitudes are

$||\vec{n_1}||=3$

$||\vec{n_2}||=\sqrt{5+k^2}$

So if I put all of it together I have $$\frac\pi3=\cos^{-1}\frac{2k}{3\sqrt{5+k^2}}$$
And I'm stuck here, I'm not even sure that the work above is what I was supposed to do, but if it is correct where should I go from here?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct so far, all that is left is to solve for $k$.
$$cos(\frac{\pi}3) = \frac{2k}{3\sqrt{5+k^2}}$$
$$\frac{1}2 = \frac{2k}{3\sqrt{5+k^2}}$$
Squaring both sides,
$$\frac{1}4 = \frac{4k^2}{9(5+k^2)}$$
$$\frac{1}4 = \frac{4k^2}{45+9k^2}$$
Multiplying both sides by $45+9k^2$,
$$\frac{45+9k^2}4 = 4k^2$$
Multiplying both sides by $4$,
$$45+9k^2 = 16k^2$$
Simplifying,
$$45=7k^2$$
$$\frac{45}7 = k^2$$
$$k = \pm\sqrt{\frac{45}7} = \pm3\sqrt{\frac{5}7}$$

Comment: The angle between two planes isn't in necessarily the angle between their normals...

Comment: Any reason for rejecting the negative root?

Comment: Thanks, forgot to add the possibility of a negative

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{2k}{3\sqrt{5+k^2}}=\cos\frac\pi3=\frac{1}{2}$$

Squaring both sides